# Problem installing some icon themes

Tags: permissions, themes, icons

Downloaded a few icon themes. Some of the themes instructed me to move the icon folder to the /.icons directory. After that the instructions state to cd to the /.icons/iconthemefolder. I'm issue the command to move the icon folder to the /.icons directory but when I issue the command to cd to the icons folder within the /.icons directory I get the error message 'No such file or directory'.

Am I not really moving the icon folder to the /.icons directory? I have to use sudo or root terminal to move the file. When I try to open the /.icons directory I get 'Permission denied'. So I can't really tell if the icon folder is really there or not. I'm running Xubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: could you edit your question to contain what command you used to move the directory? Also could you make distinct which icon folder you are talking about? In your question it is difficult to discern whether you are talking about /.icons or iconsthemefolder at different times throughout the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you copy there with root permission it is no wonder, that you can't open it with normal user privileges. I suggest, that you should not to use terminal for this, simply download the icon theme (I assume it is a package archive) open it with Archive Manager, and simply extract it to the `.icons` folder.